# Hide post from displaying in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, hide

I've inherited a wordpress site and I am having a hard time understanding how posts are being displayed.  I want to hide a couple from view (but still be able to give out a URL to view them).  I'm not familiar with the way a particular template was coded. The template outputs an image and blurb for each event in a certain category.  The meat of code that is spitting this out look like this:

```
<?php 
$args['post_type']='seasonalevents';
$args['posts_per_page']=-1;
$args['orderby'] = 'menu_order';

$activities = new WP_Query( $args );


while ( $activities->have_posts() ) : $activities->the_post();
 $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
     $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'thumb_345_154', true);
?>
```

Is there any way I can exclude post ID's within the code above?  Any hints or tips?  Feel totally baffled by this.  The variables are defined above this code snippet.  I can post if needed.

thanks!

Comment: Have you referred to the function reference for this method? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wordpress-y way to do this would be to add an element to the $args array under the three you already have:

```
$args['post__not_in'] = array(123,456,789);
```

Where 123, 456, and 789 are the ids of the posts you want to exlude from showing on this page.

So your whole code would look like:

```
<?php 
$args['post_type']='seasonalevents';
$args['posts_per_page']=-1;
$args['orderby'] = 'menu_order';
$args['post__not_in'] = array(123,456,789);

$activities = new WP_Query( $args );


while ( $activities->have_posts() ) : $activities->the_post();
 $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
     $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'thumb_345_154', true);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This makes sense.  It's weird, it works at first but if you click on the seasonal events nav item, it displays all the hidden posts.  There are a couple of things in the anchor tag: data-type="all-posts" data-taxnomy="seasonalevents_category" data-post="seasonalevents" do you think that is overriding the post exclusions?

Comment: @Peachy, you probably have multiple templates. The php file you are editing above is being used at first, but when you click on the seasonal events nav item, it's probably using a different php file to display the posts. There's a pretty good wordpress plugin called "What the file" that will show you (when you are logged in), what template files are being used to display the current page.

Comment: It doesn't seem so - but you may be right.  The side bar, which has the nav in it, has the follwing code:

$args = array(
 'parent'                   => 28,
 'orderby'                  => 'menu_order',
 'taxonomy'                 => 'seasonalevents_category');

 $categories2 = get_categories( $args );

Could that be creating the problem?

Comment: It's possible. Sometimes, depending on how the theme is coded, you can have a second loop which may override and mess up the first. Just for test, you could add the `post__not_in` arg to that and see if that affects the main loop. There's also the possibility of multiple sidebars.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is!
You can get the current post's ID using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID
I recommend you looking into 'the loop' and what that is.

This code snippet should do the job :-)

```
...
$not_these = array(1, 2, 7 /* array with post id's you got somewhere */);
while ( $activities->have_posts() ) : $activities->the_post();
    if(in_array(get_the_ID(), $not_these)) continue;
    ...
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest solution is to unpublish that post from your administration panel.

Or

```
<?php 
// The Loop
while($query->have_posts()): 
    $query->the_post();
    if(get_the_ID()!=YOUR_POST_ID):
    ?> 
    <!-- Show Post -->

    <?php
    endif;
endwhile;   
?>
```